# Merge the src folder in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How can I merge the src folder in eclipse without showing the packages,into a single folder.
[image]i

Comment: That looks like a Maven style project with three separate source folders - not packages.

Comment: If you don't need resources nor tests, you can remove the lower two source folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that, as @C-Otto said if you don't need resources or tests then they can remove as source folders. And these are not packages.
To remove as source folders.
Goto:
***Project->Properties->Build Path->Sources Tab*** and remove what you wish :)